# How to check membership from current user and set readonly of some fields when override ListFieldIterator?

Tags: 2010, list

I have created a custom ListForm template and overide the ListFieldIterator.

I have for example 10 fields in my content type. 5 of these 10 fields must be shown for the creator of the item. The other 5 must be exluded. So I need to check if this is a new item and not an exiting item.

Step 2, we need to check if the item is existing, and the user is going to edit it, I would like to check if the user is member of an custom usergroup. If it is member of this usergroup, I would like to show all the fields and exlude 0 fields. Otherwise, if the user is not a member of the usergroup I would like to show all the 10 fields, but 5 of the 10 fields need to be readonly.

```
public class CustomListFieldIterator : ListFieldIterator
{
    protected override bool IsFieldExcluded(SPField field)
    {
        if(this is an new item)
        {
            // show only 5 fields
        }
        else
        {
            // this is an existing item, you are editing this item
            // check if the current user is member of an custom usergroup "Auditors"
            SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
            int groupId = site.Groups["Auditors"].ID;
            if (site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupId))
            {
                // show all the fields
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // show all the fields, but 5 of the 10 fields READONLY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I defined my custom contenttype as follow with a reference to my custom listForm template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0100839f032740084ac2ae6ea6ab45928a65"
               Name="MyCustomContentType"
               Group="MyCustomContentType"
               Description="MyCustomContentType"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>

      <!-- These are 5 fields always visible-->
      <!-- Everybody is enabled to edit these fields -->
      <FieldRef ID="{EBC17A5D-F320-43D0-A275-7C657EA6F6C9}" Name="RFCDescription"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{76BF7D5B-6A12-48D1-9827-ADE990B03216}" Name="RFCCompany"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{9C9ED55A-7025-47F4-9637-27D5D2A1BCAE}" Name="RFCDepartment" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{87DA58EB-3C70-4EF4-B833-1D4A93D60AC9}" Name="RFCClient"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{56398822-7A4F-4155-A875-ADD09F32D4F2}" Name="RFCContact"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>


      <!-- These are 5 fields only visible in edit mode -->
      <!-- only users in usergroup "Auditors" may change these fields, otherwise readonly -->
      <FieldRef ID="{1A64CE4A-716C-4572-B344-E7CCFE443D50}" Name="RFCScope"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{39BC744E-08D4-410C-9D66-B728221634F5}" Name="RFCOperatingCosts"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{09B7ED41-C5D0-4B8F-B102-F698164A05B9}" Name="RFCExpertise"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{C95F5617-0C01-49F2-AA5C-8ADE757901F4}" Name="RFCPriority"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D6E32A83-D6FD-431B-B2CB-625516D3935F}" Name="RFCDatePlanned"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>

<FieldRef ID="{427E04A8-45E5-4243-BFE9-5FDF6FC6205B}" Name="RFCState" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>

    </FieldRefs>

    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>MyCustomListFormTemplate</Display>
          <Edit>MyCustomListFormTemplate</Edit>
          <New>MyCustomListFormTemplate</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>

  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

I have implemted 5 fields will be visible in new and edit mode. The other 5 fields will be only visible in edit mode.

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Iam using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different problems here (plus that it also matters where you use this code).

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
```

To check if a particular user is member of a certain group:

```
SPGroup managerGroup = site.Groups["ReplaceWithGroupName"];
bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup);
```

and for the Current user is easier

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["GroupName"];
if (group.ContainsCurrentUser)
{
  // your code here to hide fields
}
```

For the 2nd part however SharePoint does not provide the capability to hide FIELDS per Request/User, etc.  - you hide them - is for everyone, so updating Fields Visibility is not a solution for you in such situation.

I would go for an easier solution more maintainable solution, that would rely on injecting Javascript in the actual page (via SPD) or a CEWP to control the rendering of fields, by disabling/hiding controls. It is possible to detect in which group the user is part of using details here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-ZA/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/dee33fe3-a067-455a-aa65-3bc9bab2e761

Comment: Is something like this not possible??



 if(condition)

 {

field.ReadOnlyField = true;

                        field.Update();

}

Comment: I've updated my answer - do consider ECMA Javascript as an alternative. When you update a field as in your comment, it shall be the same for everyone.

Comment: @user1326231, you can do it without javascript, using custom `ListFieldIterator` only

Answer (score 0):

You can set display in new/edit form property of field to FALSE in the list schema and then add asp controls for these fields to you custom form template. After this you should override

```
OnSaveContext SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler += OnItemSaved;
```

In OnItemSaved handler you can collect data from controls and fill item fields.

Comment: You are right, but this does not resolve the issue of hiding/showing selectively fields, unless the New/Edit forms are totally rebuilt - which with C# code is really not sustainable.

Comment: @C.Marius, you can use `control.visible = group.ContainsCurrentUser` in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you need to override `CreateChildControls` in addition to `IsFieldExcluded`.

Here is a full code for your custom list field iterator:

```
public class CustomListFieldIterator : ListFieldIterator
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        if (this.ControlTemplate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not find ListFieldIterator control template.");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < base.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            SPField field = base.Fields[i];
            if (!this.IsFieldExcluded(field))
            {
                var child = new CompositeField();
                child.ControlMode = base.ControlMode;
                child.FieldName = field.InternalName;
                var auditors = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups["Auditors"].ID;
                bool isAuditor = SPContext.Current.Web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(auditors);

                //if field is "Title", we in edit mode and user is not Auditor, make field readonly
                if (field.InternalName.Equals("Title") && ControlMode == SPControlMode.Edit && !isAuditor)
                {
                    child.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
                }
                this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
                this.Controls.Add(child);
                Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
            }
        }

    }

    protected override bool IsFieldExcluded(SPField field)
    {
        if (base.IsFieldExcluded(field))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //exclude field "Title" in new mode
        if (base.ControlMode == SPControlMode.New)
        {
            if (field.InternalName.Equals("Title"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some explanation:
 - Field "Title" excluded in a new mode for all users.
 - In edit mode field "Title" set as read only for all users, excepts "Auditors" group members.

I have to made a little trick with overriding `CreateChildControls` to insert on page `CompositeField` with different `ControlMode` depending on group membership. `CompositeField` is actually a control, which render `CompositeField` rendering template (you can find it in DefaultTemplates.ascx).

So, this can be done without javascript.
  Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Your solution relies on Application page being built, as building a EDIT/NEW form in such way is not the recomanded way and besides it complicates the deployment or migration

Comment: Where did I mention that this is an application page? It's not an application page, it's custom `ListFieldIterator` class, which is embed as sharepoint rendered template. Look at this [article](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/listfielditerator/). You can also google another lot of examples of using it in new\edit forms

Comment: This works..But..Do I need to add the 5 field title names in the if below:

if (field.InternalName.Equals("Title") && field.InternalName.Equals("Field2") && field.InternalName.Equals("Field3") && field.InternalName.Equals("Field4") &&
field.InternalName.Equals("Field5") && ControlMode == SPControlMode.Edit && !isAuditor)
                    {
                        child.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
                    }

Comment: To simplify I recommend you to create `List<string>` of your excluded fields, and then do following check: `if (myExcludedFields.Contains(field.InternalName) && ControlMode == SPControlMode.Edit && !isAuditor) { child.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display; } `

Comment: The ListFieldIterator could be very well used in Application pages (exactly as the article also expresses). Your solution is certainly doable, but it requires compiled code, not Sandbox either.

Comment: @C.Marius, when talking about using ListFieldIterator in list forms, it's very clear that **we are not using application pages** (this is a bad practice, as you mentioned). And I can't see any requirements about sandboxed solution in user1326231 message. He asked a question regarding custom ListFieldIterator and custom form templates, so my answer is exactly what he want. user1326231 will correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Is there a better way to set readonly on some fields depandent by the current user?

Comment: If this method doesn't match your requirements, you may consider javascript approach, as @C.Marius proposed.